# JMS Serializer on Symfony2 : work with timestamps instead of datetimes

Tags: symfony, serialization, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I make a webservice using Symfony2, FOSRestBundle and of course JMS Serializer. Webservice clients are dealing with timestamps instead of ISO Formated DateTimes.

I'd like JMS Serializer to convert inputs from timestamps to DateTimes and outputs from DateTimes to timestamps.

I tried to put this annotation on my attribute:

```
/**
 * Start of validity
 *
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="validityStart", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 *
 * @Assert\Type(type="integer",message="Validity dates must be timestamps. [{{ value }}] is incorrect.")
 *
 * @Serializer\Expose()
 * @Serializer\Groups({"ticket_detail","ticket_list"})
 * @Serializer\Type("DateTime<'U'>")
 *
 */
private $validityStart;
```

When I do this, I get this error on form validation:

```
"validityStart": {
        "errors": [
          "This value is not valid."
        ],
        "children": {
          "date": {
            "children": {
              "year": [],
              "month": [],
              "day": []
            }
          },
          "time": {
            "children": {
              "hour": [],
              "minute": []
            }
          }
        }
```

Do you see how I can get JMS Serializer doing the job ?

*EDIT:* The @Serializer\Type annotation works well on output. But I still have a problem for input...

*EDIT 2:* Here is my form builder

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('validityStart', 'datetime',
                array(  'format'=>'U',
                        'required'=>false,
                        'description'=>'The message validity start timestamp')
            )
            ->add('validityEnd', 'integer',
                array(  'required'=>false,
                        'description'=>'The message validity end timestamp')
            )
        ;
    }
```

I tried two ways to do it, the second way seems to work ! But I get this error after passing form validation:

```
"message": "Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object",
        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException",
        "trace": [
          {
            "namespace": "",
            "short_class": "",
            "class": "",
            "type": "",
            "function": "",
            "file": "/var/www/symfony/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/DateTimeType.php",
            "line": 53,
            "args": []
          },...
```

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, I would go with a virtual property and not expose the original one.
Maybe not best practice but I think you can also override the get function and convert it there.

Comment: I'm open to any idea to solve this but indeed, Virtual Properties are only working for serialization (output). The @Serializer/Type annotation works very well for serialization ! The issue is on deserialization...

Comment: Could you also post the form you re using for this?

Comment: I posted it. The error changed when I set the field to an integer

Comment: I suppose you put also validitystart at integer in your form. Actually after you need a data transformer to convert the "integer" to a datetime. Have a look at this doc:
http://symfony2-document.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html